# How to pause the output of Powershell from a bat file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I need to see the powershell output when I'm running it from a bat file.  The bat file pauses with no problem but the powershell executes and flashes on the screen and closes before I can read the powershell error.  How can I pause the powershell output so I can read it.

Bat file RemovePackagesFitBit.bat

```
@ECHO Off
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%~dpn0.ps1""' -Verb RunAs} | Wait-Process"
@PAUSE
```

Powershell file RemovePackagesFitBit.PS1

```
Get-AppxPackage -allusers *fitbit* | Remove-AppxPackage
```

Running this in Windows 10

Comment: PLEASE fix you code formatting. right now, it is difficult to determine what is code versus what aint code.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert pause in script where required:

```
$Package = Get-AppxPackage -allusers -Name fitbit
Pause
$Packasge | Remove-AppxPackage
Pause
```

Comment: Thank you.  It does pause now.  I still don't see the output of the powershell commands. They flash on the screen too fast for me to see the error.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to see the errors with a pause so I logged all output to a file this way:
I put this at the begining of the script:

```
 $Logfile = "C:\Temp\Fix-Sysprep.log"
 If (Test-Path $Logfile)
 {
 Remove-item -path $Logfile
 }
 Start-Transcript -Path $Logfile -Append
```

I put this at the end of the script:

```
 Stop-Transcript
```